# When auto is used against array, why it's converted to pointer and not reference?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, language-design

See the below example:

```
int arr[10];
int *p = arr; // 1st valid choice
int (&r)[10] = arr; // 2nd valid choice
```

Now when we use `auto` against `arr` then, it chooses the 1st choice.

```
auto x = arr; // x is equivalent to *p
```

Is there a reason for [choosing a pointer and not reference](http://www.ideone.com/pCV3J) for array ?

Comment: What kind of *Why* is that? *Why* as in "which part of the standard says so", or *why* as in "why did the committee decide to do it this way"?

Comment: 2nd **why**. Because 1st *why* is dependent on the 2nd one. :)

Comment: Exactly the same reason why `int i = 0; auto a = i;` yields an `int` and not an `int&`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To provide a standard reference for the behavior, 7.1.6.4 [dcl.spec.auto] paragraph 6 reads:

> Once the type of a declarator-id has been determined according to 8.3, the type of the declared variable using the declarator-id is determined from the type of its initializer using the rules for template argument deduction. Let T be the type that has been determined for a variable identifier d. Obtain P from T by replacing the occurrences of auto with ... a new invented type template parameter U ... The type deduced for the variable d is then the deduced A determined using the rules of template argument deduction from a function call (14.8.2.1), where P is a function template parameter type and the initializer for d is the corresponding argument. If the deduction fails, the declaration is ill-formed.

So we need to look elsewhere, specifically 14.8.2.1 [tmp.deduct.call] paragraph 2:

> If P is not a reference type: — If A is an array type, the pointer type produced by the array-to-pointer standard conversion (4.2) is used in place of A for type deduction

For completeness sake, 4.2 [conv.array] paragraph 1:

> An lvalue or rvalue of type “array of N T” or “array of unknown bound of T” can be converted to a prvalue of type “pointer to T”. The result is a pointer to the first element of the array.

To step through it, `auto x = arr;` creates an imaginary function `template<typename P> f(P);` and attempts to deduce `P` from the call `f(arr)`.  `A` in this case is `array of 10 int`, and `P` is not a reference type, so `A` becomes `pointer to int` instead.  Which percolates up the chain back into the final type of `x`.

So basically, it is treated as a pointer because the rules say it must.  The behavior is simply more useful this way, since arrays are not assignable.  Otherwise, your `auto x = arr;` would fail to compile rather than do something useful.

Answer (score 27):

Yes. In that expression, the array decays into pointer type, due to `lvalue-to-rvalue` conversion.

If you want *array* type , not *pointer* type, then do this:

```
auto & x = arr; //now it doesn't decay into pointer type!
```

`&` in the target type prevents the array from decaying into pointer type!

---

`x` is an array and not a pointer, can be proved as:

```
void f(int (&a)[10]) 
{
    std::cout << "f() is called. that means, x is an array!" << std::endl;
}
int main() {
     int arr[10];
     auto & x = arr; 
     f(x); //okay iff x is an int array of size 10, else compilation error!
}
```

Output:

```
f() is called. that means, x is an array!
```

Demo at ideone : http://www.ideone.com/L2Ifp

Note that `f` *cannot* be called with *pointer* type. It can be called with an `int` array of size `10`.  Attempting to call it with *any* other type, will result in compilation error.

Comment: @karlphillip: Which question? Did I ask any question here?

Comment: @Nawaz: it happens because the rvalue is expected, but not exactly due to lvalue-to-rvalue conversion. Rather due to array-to-pointer conversion

Comment: (from paragraph 8 of §5 in the standard: "Whenever a glvalue expression appears as an operand of an operator that expects a prvalue for that operand
the lvalue-to-rvalue (4.1), array-to-pointer (4.2), or function-to-pointer (4.3) standard conversions are applied[...]")

Answer (score 4):

`auto` produces values. It will not produce references. With this in mind, then the pointer is the trivial conversion to a value that the array offers.

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by *`auto` produces values*?

Comment: @Space_C0wb0y: what I understand by that, is that for example `int y = 0; auto x = y;` doesn't produce a reference-to-int. In fact it turns out that `auto` alone never defines a reference, that's what `auto &` is for. The RHS being an array is no exception - `auto` alone doesn't define a reference, it defines an object. `int*` and `const int*` are the *only* object types for which the expression `arr` is a valid initializer, so clearly `x` must have type `int*`, which is the type of the expression `arr` as an rvalue.

Comment: Note that if arrays were copyable/assignable then we'd have an ambiguity here, maybe `auto x = arr` should define an array, and the standard would have to resolve it. But they aren't, so there isn't.

Comment: Another example of `auto` deducing a value type rather than a reference type is something like this: `vector<int> v{1,2,3}; auto i = v.front();`  `decltype(vector<int>::front())` is `int&`, but `decltype(i)` is just plain `int`.

Comment: @Dennis: Aye; worth remembering when we all start using `auto` habitually.

Answer (score 0):

For an array `arr`, the expression `arr` itself means `&arr[0]`. This rule comes from C. Therefore, IMO, auto chooses pointer.

Comment: It is a little more tricky than that in C++, where `arr` as an lvalue expression is a reference to the array, but as an rvalue expression decays into a pointer...

Comment: Agreed. But a C++ compiler first tries to follow C rules, and not C++ rules. And that's why presumably allocated local variable via `string mystring();` results in error. I also agree `auto`, in new sense, is C++ specific - but there are cases where brackets are required around templates to "tell" C++ compiler to treat it as C++ code, and not C code.

Comment: What? A C++ compiler follows the C++ rules first and only. If they match the C language they will do the same, if they don't they will behave as a C++ compiler. In this particular case, if it were following the C rules the definition would be parsed as `auto int x = arr;`, and the error would be a failure to convert from `int*` to `int`. And I don't understand the `string` case, the parsing rules for that particular expression are stated in the C++ standard, and they coincide with the C standard only in as much as there is no namespace qualifications, like in `std::string mystring();`