# C++1y/C++14: Converting static constexpr array to non-type template parameter pack?

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, constexpr, c++14

Suppose I have a constexpr array (of known bound) of static storage duration:

```
constexpr T input[] = /* ... */;
```

And I have an output class template that needs a pack:

```
template<T...> struct output_template;
```

I want to instantiate `output_template` like:

```
using output = output_template<input[0], input[1], ..., input[n-1]>;
```

One way to do this is:

```
template<size_t n, const T (&a)[n]>
struct make_output_template
{
    template<size_t... i> static constexpr
    output_template<a[i]...> f(std::index_sequence<i...>)
    { return {}; };

    using type = decltype(f(std::make_index_sequence<n>()));
};

using output = make_output_template<std::extent_v<decltype(input)>, input>::type;
```

Is there a cleaner or simpler solution I am missing?

Comment: what are you looking for? simpler interface or implementation?

Comment: Could [the indices trick](http://loungecpp.wikidot.com/tips-and-tricks:indices) be useful here? You don't have a template index parameter to play with here, as you would with a tuple, but...

Comment: `using output = decltype(deduce(input))::unpack<input>;`? Not much cleaner, though.

Comment: @dyp linkage of `a` seems to be the hurdle (even with more `constexpr` in appropriate places): http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2c196c6f2a82cbfb

Comment: @TemplateRex That's what clang says ;) But indeed, addresses used as non-type template arguments must refer to objects with linkage, IIRC due to name mangling. The rule what is allowed as an address argument is very strict, it doesn't even allow derived-to-base conversions.

Comment: @TemplateRex: It's not that. It's just that you can't use a constexpr function parameter as a template argument, as it isn't a constant expression.  `constexpr int f(int a) { constexpr int b = a; return b; } // ill-formed.`

Comment: @TemplateRex: A function call to a constexpr function (with constant arguments) is a constant expression, yes - however within the body of the contexpr function definition the parameters are not constant expressions.

Comment: It seems like this is another potential application of [proposal n3601](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3601.html), which would allow `using output = foo<input>;` as far as I can see.

Comment: @dyp I though of an easier syntax to improve N3601: `template<auto V>` where `V` is a compile-time **value** and the **type** can be easily accessed with `decltype(V)`. When I asked Mike and Daveed (the authors of N3601) about it, it turns out they also already came up with the exact same idea and syntax and want to prepare an updated version of N3601 :)

Comment: @DanielFrey ... I think I've seen this somewhere before.. but I cannot remember where or find it. Edit: maybe http://stackoverflow.com/q/5628121 or https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/#!topic/std-proposals/fxGaLhamuFw

Comment: @dyp Looks like several people arrived at the same conclusion independently - which is IMHO a very good sign that this is the best syntax/solution :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Maybe you consider this to be cleaner:

```
template< const T* a, typename >
struct make_output_template;

template< const T* a, std::size_t... i >
struct make_output_template< a, std::index_sequence< i... > >
{
    using type = output_template< a[ i ]... >;
};
```

with

```
using output = make_output_template<
    input,
    std::make_index_sequence< std::extent_v< decltype( input ) > >
>::type;
```

Comment: I do indeed sir, thanks.  I guess all the examples of index_sequence I have seen use deduction of function parameters so I didn't think to use partial specicialization on the class.

Comment: There is no language specific feature that could stop me to try this using C++11, isn't?

Comment: @Manu343726 Yes, you are right, all it needs it C++11 once you replaced `std::extend_v<...>` with `std::extend<...>::value` and you rolled your own version of `std::make_index_sequence`.

Answer (score 0):

**C++ 17 update:** With auto template parameters, we can make both OP's solution and [Daniel Frey's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24564866/8805602) answer a bit nicer to use. In OP's case:

```
template<auto& input>
using output = make_output_template<std::extent_v<std::remove_reference_t<decltype(input)>>, input>::type;
```

which can be used directly, e.g.: `outupt<input> foo;`.

Be sure to use `auto&` to capture the array correctly. With bare `auto` it will decay into a regular pointer (see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/6443267), `std::extent_v` will be zero, but the code can still compile, and if you expect the variadic pack in `output_template` to be of the same size as the `input` array, you have a brand new bug.